# Not found version `XCRYPT_2.0' in libcrypt.so.1 even I installed it at lib64

Tags: linux, gdb

I was debugging use GDB on Cent OS but it needs 'libcrypt.so'. So I installed debuginfo-install glibc.
But it says not found 'XCRYPT_2.0'.
How can I fix it ?
Please help me.
[image]

Comment: If you don’t use GDB, does the program still get  the shared library error?

Answer (score 1):

```
# dnf provides \*/libcrypt.so.1
libxcrypt-4.1.1-4.el8.i686 : Extended crypt library for DES, MD5, Blowfish and others
Repo                       : BaseOS
Matched from               :
Filename                   : /lib/libcrypt.so.1

# dnf search libxcrypt
========== Name Exactly Matched: libxcrypt ==========
libxcrypt.x86_64 : Extended crypt library for DES, MD5, Blowfish and others
........

# dnf install libxcrypt
```

**EDIT**

Also check location of `libcrypt.so.1` in your case its asking for `/lib64/` and on my centos8 resolve its location in `/lib/`